# Parsing pinterest JSON api with PHP

Tags: php, json, parsing, pinterest

Hi im having problem parsing this pinterest JSON file, any ideas? thanks

```
    $json = file_get_contents('http://pinterestapi.co.uk/jwmoz/boards');

    $obj = json_decode($json);
    foreach($obj->body as $item){
    $example = $item[0]->name;
    echo $example;
    }
```

```
    {
    "body":[
      {"name":"JMOZ",
      "href":"http:\/\/pinterest.com\/jwmoz\/jmoz\/",
      "num_of_pins":17,"cover_src":"http:\/\/media-cache-ec4.pinterest.com\/upload\/82190761920643849_2DcDfCUK_222.jpg",
      "thumbs_src":
          ["http:\/\/media-cache-ec5.pinterest.com\/upload\/82190761920643841_dZfvCWmE_t.jpg",
          "http:\/\/media-cache-ec4.pinterest.com\/upload\/82190761920194573_aPAbDtHD_t.jpg",
          "http:\/\/media-cache-ec2.pinterest.com\/upload\/82190761920194563_dQcOIHvQ_t.jpg",
          "http:\/\/media-cache0.pinterest.com\/upload\/82190761920194557_VSSI2uQB_t.jpg"
          ]
      },
      {"name":"JMOZ",
      "href":"http:\/\/pinterest.com\/jwmoz\/jmoz\/",
      "num_of_pins":17,"cover_src":"http:\/\/media-cache-ec4.pinterest.com\/upload\/82190761920643849_2DcDfCUK_222.jpg",
      "thumbs_src":
          ["http:\/\/media-cache-ec5.pinterest.com\/upload\/82190761920643841_dZfvCWmE_t.jpg",
          "http:\/\/media-cache-ec4.pinterest.com\/upload\/82190761920194573_aPAbDtHD_t.jpg",
          "http:\/\/media-cache-ec2.pinterest.com\/upload\/82190761920194563_dQcOIHvQ_t.jpg",
          "http:\/\/media-cache0.pinterest.com\/upload\/82190761920194557_VSSI2uQB_t.jpg"
          ]
      },     
      {"name":"JMOZ",
      "href":"http:\/\/pinterest.com\/jwmoz\/jmoz\/",
      "num_of_pins":17,"cover_src":"http:\/\/media-cache-ec4.pinterest.com\/upload\/82190761920643849_2DcDfCUK_222.jpg",
      "thumbs_src":
          ["http:\/\/media-cache-ec5.pinterest.com\/upload\/82190761920643841_dZfvCWmE_t.jpg",
          "http:\/\/media-cache-ec4.pinterest.com\/upload\/82190761920194573_aPAbDtHD_t.jpg",
          "http:\/\/media-cache-ec2.pinterest.com\/upload\/82190761920194563_dQcOIHvQ_t.jpg",
          "http:\/\/media-cache0.pinterest.com\/upload\/82190761920194557_VSSI2uQB_t.jpg"
          ]
      },
      {"name":"test I\u00f1t\u00ebrn\u00e2ti\u00f4n\u00e0liz\u00e6ti\u00f8n",
       "href":"http:\/\/pinterest.com\/jwmoz\/test-internationaliztin\/",
       "num_of_pins":0,
       "cover_src":false,
       "thumbs_src":false
       }],
      "meta":{"count":11}
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem is in your usage of the [0] index on $item

```
$example = $item[0]->name;
```

This should just be

```
$example = $item->name;
```

To access the thumbnails, try

```
$obj = json_decode($json);
foreach($obj->body as $item){
  echo '<li>' . $item->name . '<ul>';
  if(!empty($item->thumbs_src))
  {
    foreach($item->thumbs_src as $thumbs_src){
      echo '<li>' . $thumbs_src . '</li>';
    }
  }
  echo '</ul></li>';
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my answer, the problem was with the usage of _$item[0]->name_